# Inserir valores de 0 a 15 no teclado em assembly fasm x86

Tags: assembly, x86

Boas. Eu tenho que fazer um programa em assembly que le um numero do teclado que é para escolher uma cor no modo video. De 0 a 9 sei que é assim:

```
mov ah, 40h                  ;Pedir um valor
mov bx, 1
mov cx, 44
mov dx, pergunta
int 21h


mov ah, 3Fh                     ;Introduzir valor
mov bx, 0
mov cx, 1
mov dx, valor
int 21h

sub [valor],48
```

Agora preciso de ajuda para ser de 0 a 15

Comment: Amigo, os interrupts são totalmente dependentes do sistema operacional usado, exceto que estejas no *real mode*. Como fazes? Está em Linux, Windows, DOS (real mode)? O mais provavel é que você pegue dois valores do teclado e os some ao estilo decimal (0->1)*10 + (0->9)